# java.sql.SQLException:with infinite loop

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

In my project "Student Attendance Management System" , after giving the subject name and number of roll nos present, my project start adding the "1" to the given subject infinitely,and it also shows error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set

Here is my Teacher_Window.java:

```
 import java.sql.Connection;
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
 import java.sql.ResultSet;
 import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.sql.Statement;
 import java.util.logging.Level;
 import java.util.logging.Logger;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
 import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
 import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
 import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;


public class Teacher_Window extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID=1L;

public Teacher_Window() throws SQLException {
    initComponents();
    populate_attendance_table();        //method definition is written below
}


@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "serial" })
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    class_attendance = new javax.swing.JTable();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    update_attendance_btn = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setTitle("Attendance Card");
    setAutoRequestFocus(false);

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(102, 153, 255));
    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Attendance Card", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.LEFT, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 24), new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255))); // NOI18N

    class_attendance.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 255, 255));
    class_attendance.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        new Object [][] {

        },
        new String [] {
                 "Roll_no", "Name", "Tamil Attended", "Tamil Total", "English Attended", "English Total", "Maths Attended", "Maths Total","Science Attended","Science Total","Social Attended","Social Total", "Attendance(%)"
        }
    ) {
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Class[] types = new Class [] {
            java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class,java.lang.Integer.class,java.lang.Integer.class,java.lang.Integer.class,java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Float.class
        };

        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
            return types [columnIndex];
        }
    });
    jScrollPane1.setViewportView(class_attendance);

    jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 153, 255));
    jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "----------", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 13), new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255))); // NOI18N

    update_attendance_btn.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    update_attendance_btn.setText("Update Attendance");
    update_attendance_btn.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
    update_attendance_btn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            update_attendance_btnActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 18)); // NOI18N
    jButton2.setText("Get Student Details");
    jButton2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
    jButton2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(153, 27));
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(257, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(update_attendance_btn, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 217, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(229)
                .addComponent(jButton2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 222, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(272))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(72)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(update_attendance_btn, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 51, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(59, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 482, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

public void populate_attendance_table() throws SQLException         //to diplay attendance table contents in jTable
    {
        Connection conn=null;
                try {
                    //DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
                    DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) class_attendance.getModel();
                    //setRowColour(1, Color.YELLOW);
                    conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/attendance","root","happy");
                    Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();
                   
                   int rowCount = dtm.getRowCount();
                    //clear the class_attendance table before filling it everytime
                    for (int i = rowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        dtm.removeRow(i);
                    }
                    ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select a.Roll_no,sd.name,a.tamil,a.t,a.english,a.e,a.maths,a.m,a.science,a.s,a.social,a.so,a.Attendance from attendance a,details sd WHERE a.Roll_no=sd.rollno order by a.Roll_no");
                    //testResultSet(rs);
                    ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
                    int numberOfColumns;
                    numberOfColumns = meta.getColumnCount();
                    while(rs.next()){
                        Object [] rowData = new Object[numberOfColumns];
                        for (int i = 0; i < rowData.length; ++i)
                        {
                            rowData[i] = rs.getObject(i+1);
                            if(i==rowData.length-1)     //when last column i.e. attendaance column calculate attendance and update
                            {
                                int total_attended=((int)rowData[2]+(int)rowData[4]+(int)rowData[6]+(int)rowData[8]+(int)rowData[10]);           //subject1+subject2+subject3
                                int total_lectures=((int)rowData[3]+(int)rowData[5]+(int)rowData[7]+(int)rowData[9]+(int)rowData[11]);           //S1+S2+S3
                                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+total_attended+" "+total_lectures,"", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                float result=((float)total_attended/(float)total_lectures)*100;
                                rowData[i]=(float)(result);             //Attendance=(Subject1+Subject2+Subject3)/(S1+S2+S3);
                               // JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,total_attended+" "+total_lectures+" "+result,"", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                                
                            }
                            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+rowData[i],"", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                        }
                        dtm.addRow(rowData);
                        //dtm.addRow(new Object[]{"Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3","Column 1", "Column 2", "Column 3"});
                        dtm.fireTableDataChanged();
                        //dtm.fireTableStructureChanged();
                    }


                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(attendance.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                conn.close();
    }




private void update_attendance_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_update_attendance_btnActionPerformed
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    
    String subject_name= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the subject name: ");
    String rollnos = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the roll numbers of the present students: ");
   String subject_present=null;
   if(subject_name.equalsIgnoreCase("Tamil"))
   {
       subject_present="t";
   }
   else if(subject_name.equalsIgnoreCase("English"))
   {
       subject_present="e";
   }
   else if(subject_name.equalsIgnoreCase("Maths"))
   {
       subject_present="m";
   }
   else if(subject_name.equalsIgnoreCase("Science"))
   {
       subject_present="s";
   }
   else if(subject_name.equalsIgnoreCase("Social"))
   {
       subject_present="so";
   }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid subject name!","", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        try {
            new Teacher_Window().setVisible(true);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Teacher_Window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    int cnt=0;
    String[] rno = rollnos.split(",");              // to split the roll no list

    Connection conn=null;
    Statement stmt=null;
   while(cnt<rno.length)
   {
       //System.out.println(rno[cnt++]);
   
    
            try {
                //DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
                DefaultTableModel dtm = (DefaultTableModel) class_attendance.getModel();
                conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/attendance","root","happy");
                stmt=conn.createStatement();
                
                //int sub_name=Integer.parseInt(subject_name);
                //sub_name++;
                //subject_name=""+sub_name;
                //System.out.println("Updated Subject count:"+subject_name);
                           
              
            
                stmt.executeUpdate("update attendance set "+subject_name+"="+subject_name+"+1"+" where Roll_no="+rno[cnt]); //increment total attended lecture count of that subject
               
                //calculate updated attendance percentage
                ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery("select * from attendance  where Roll_no="+rno[cnt]);
                int tamil=(int)rs.getInt(2);
                int tamil_total=(int)rs.getInt(3);
                int english=(int)rs.getInt(4);
                int english_total=(int)rs.getInt(5);
                int maths=(int)rs.getInt(6);
                int maths_total=(int)rs.getInt(7);
                int sci=(int)rs.getInt(8);
                int sci_total=(int)rs.getInt(9);
                int soc=(int)rs.getInt(10);
                int soc_total=(int)rs.getInt(11);
                
                int attended=tamil+english+maths+sci+soc;
                int total=tamil_total+english_total+maths_total+sci_total+soc_total+1;            //add 1 because attended subject's total is not incremented here so we need to consider it as well
                System.out.println(tamil+"\t"+tamil_total+"\n"+english+"\t"+english_total+"\n"+maths+"\t"+maths_total+"\n"+sci+"\t"+sci_total+"\n"+soc+"\t"+soc_total);
                
                float percentage=((float)attended/(float)total)*100;
                System.out.println("Percentage:"+percentage);
                stmt.executeUpdate("update attendance set Attendance="+percentage+" where Roll_no="+rno[cnt]);   //update attendance %
                
                
                
                cnt++;
            
                } 
                catch (SQLException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(attendance.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
    }//end of while
    try {
        
            stmt.executeUpdate("update attendance set "+subject_present+"="+subject_present+"+1");     //increment total lecture count of that subject
            
           
            
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Teacher_Window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Teacher_Window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    
   
    try {
        //new Teacher_Window().setVisible(true);
        populate_attendance_table();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Attendance updated successfully!","", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Teacher_Window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}//GEN-LAST:event_update_attendance_btnActionPerformed

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    new ViewStudent().setVisible(true);             //goto student details tab
}//GEN-LAST:event_jButton2ActionPerformed

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String args[]) {
   
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Teacher_Window.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Teacher_Window.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Teacher_Window.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Teacher_Window.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                new Teacher_Window().setVisible(true);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Teacher_Window.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
private javax.swing.JTable class_attendance;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
private javax.swing.JButton update_attendance_btn;
 }
```

And the error is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:517)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getObject(ResultSetImpl.java:1314)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.result.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:822)
at Teacher_Window.update_attendance_btnActionPerformed(Teacher_Window.java:273)
at Teacher_Window$2.actionPerformed(Teacher_Window.java:88)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6626)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3389)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6391)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5001)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4833)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:773)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:744)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

Like this it goes infinitely.

Comment: 1. be happy if you get any response, be it immediate or not. 2. `int tamil=(int)rs.getInt(2);` is called before you move result set pointer to the first result. Call `rs.next();` first. `Moves the cursor forward one row from its current position.A ResultSet cursor is initially positionedbefore the first row` 3. Your update query seems wrong. Unless `subject_name` is a number in the attendance table, the update wont work as you want it

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/2670892) - never

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `update_attendance_btnActionPerformed` you are directly accessing data from `ResultSet` even before calling `rs.next()`.

```
//calculate updated attendance percentage
ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery("select * from attendance  where Roll_no="+rno[cnt]);
int tamil=(int)rs.getInt(2);
```

What you should have is :

```
ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery("select * from attendance  where Roll_no="+rno[cnt]);

 while(rs.next()){
   int tamil=(int)rs.getInt(2);
   ...
 }
```

Comment: Still same error!

Comment: what changes you did? also please check if error coming for same method.

Comment: I added "while(rs.next())" next to the resultset ,still it gives inifinate loop and the "percentage" is not updated in the database.

Comment: can you check error is coming from same method or its from some other other method

Comment: thanks ,there was an error in datatype of percentage in database,i figure it out :)

Comment: glad to know it worked !